# тег <Video> на windows phone

Tags: html5, mobile

На смартфоне nokia c операционкой win 8 тег  работает не корректно: позиционируется поверх всего остального контента и выглядит как чёрная область.

Помогите понять почему видео вылезло поверх всего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP8 (точнее IE10) не поддерживает проигрывание тэга video в браузере, точнее, насколько я помню, поддерживает только на полный экран или скачивание файла.

И подозреваю, что формат webm он тоже не умеет, поэтому и получается вместо видео ч0рный квадрат малевича.

Comment: то что не поддерживается это очень может быть. а так видео по всем правилам добавлено в 3 формата .ogg .mp4 .webm